# How to repeat RDLC table column on all page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rdlc

I need to print a barcode of an item on an A4 page.
The barcode should be repeated horizontally and vertically all over the page.

The barcode should be repeated 65 times (13 rows / 5 columns each)
How to do this ?

I am using RDLC, Visual studio 2015

Comment: Can you use a Header or Footer?

Comment: yes, no problem. if this solve my issue. but it should be repeated 65 times on the page.13 rows 5 columns

Comment: Nothing says that the heders and footers in a document can't be 95% of the page size.

Comment: i wan to repeat on all the page, how ?

Comment: The header and Footer automatically gets repeated on every page.